# How to configure babel 2.5 with api for java?

Tags: java, configuration, semantic-web

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNetConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet.<init>(BabelNet.java:119)`fdasdfas`
    at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet.getInstance(BabelNet.java:212)
    at mainPkg.BabelNetDemo.www12Test(BabelNetDemo.java:252)
    at mainPkg.BabelNetDemo.main(BabelNetDemo.java:309)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`ajhkfhs`
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)`errror`
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: I think you may need to provide more context.

Comment: at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet.getInstance(BabelNet.java:212)

Comment: By more context I meant (for instance), the code that this is getting called from (if you're calling something from code), or the configuration causing this stuff to be called), whether this is code you wrote or that someone else wrote, etc.  I could already see in the second line of the stacktrace that **it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet.getInstance(BabelNet.java:212)** is involved.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code here:
https://github.com/iucl/l2-writing-assistant/blob/master/babelnet-api-2.0/src/it/uniroma1/lcl/babelnet/BabelNet.java

I think there is a configuration file missing.

`/**
     * Used to access {@link BabelNet}
     * 
     * @return an instance of {@link BabelNet}
     */
    public static synchronized BabelNet getInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            if (instance == null) instance = new BabelNet();
            return instance;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("\nCould not init BabelNet: " + e.getMessage()+"\n" +
                    "Set the value of \"babelnet.dir=\" in the file: config/babelnet.var.properties");
        }
    }`